# React Native - What is reactTag parameter in AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus()?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

What is `reactTag` parameter in `AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(reactTag)` method? React native [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibilityinfo#setaccessibilityfocus) don't provide any information about this parameter:

> Set accessibility focus to a React component. On Android, this is equivalent 
>   to UIManager.sendAccessibilityEvent(reactTag,
>   UIManager.AccessibilityEventTypes.typeViewFocused);.

I don't have any background of `Objective-C` and `Java`. A little example will be more appreciated. Thank !!!

Comment: I've noticed that I couldn't find documentation for either `reactTag` or `findNodeHandle`, mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`reactTag` is simply a number that is used by react to identify view objects in your application. It is the result of `findNodeHandle` function, which takes a view reference as parameter.

Here's a simple example on how you can use it:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
  ...
  findNodeHandle,
  ...
} from 'react-native';

class Sample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.viewRef = null;
    }

    ...

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.viewRef) {
            const reactTag = findNodeHandle(this.viewRef);
            AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(reactTag);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View ref={el => { this.viewRef = el }}>
                ...
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, wondering if this works even when the component is already been loaded and then accessibility is enabled.
In other words, is there a possibility to set accessibility focus only when after the component is about to be focused?

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble with this solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63252638/setaccessibilityfocus-using-ref-not-working

Comment: I haven't been able to get this working, though I'm attempting to translate it to a function component. `FindNodeHandle` throws a typeerror when I try to pass it a ref, says it wants a number or component.