# Simplify this repeating code pattern on class components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently implementing accessibility (VoiceOver/Talkback) support for my application, and I use `AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus` ([see official docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibilityinfo#setaccessibilityfocus)) quite a lot which requires a reactTag, which I can only get by using `findNodeHandle` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53466244/930998).

This means that I keep repeating the same pattern involving quite a few function calls, over and over on many different components. I originally tried to move the stored references and the call to set focus to my state manager (using MobX in this case) but I ended up getting a lot of failed `findNodeHandle` calls because sometime the component had unmounted before the call was made.

This is the gist of what I keep repeating:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
  ...
  findNodeHandle,
  AccessibilityInfo
  ...
} from 'react-native';

class Sample extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.accessibilityRef = null;
    }

    ...

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setAccessibilityFocus()
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.setAccessibilityFocus()
    }

    setAccessibilityRef(el) {
        this.accessibilityRef = el
    }

    setAccessibilityFocus() {
        if (this.accessibilityRef) {
            const reactTag = findNodeHandle(this.accessibilityRef);
            AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(reactTag);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View ref={this.setAccessibilityRef} accessible={true}>
                ...
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to somehow make something reusable out of this? Maybe a decorator or as a class extension so that I can reuse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can...

Let, `SampleWrapper.js` is your wrapper.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
  ...
  findNodeHandle,
  AccessibilityInfo
  ...
} from 'react-native';

export default class SampleWrapper extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.accessibilityRef = null;
    }

    ...

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setAccessibilityFocus()
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.setAccessibilityFocus()
    }

    setAccessibilityRef(el) {
        this.accessibilityRef = el
    }

    setAccessibilityFocus() {
        if (this.accessibilityRef) {
            const reactTag = findNodeHandle(this.accessibilityRef);
            AccessibilityInfo.setAccessibilityFocus(reactTag);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View ref={this.setAccessibilityRef} accessible={true}>
                {this.props.children}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Now, assume you want to use the above wrapper in your `Sample.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import SampleWrapper from './path/to/SampleWrapper'

class Sample extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SampleWrapper>
                ....
            </SampleWrapper>
        )
    }
}
```

You can put `ref` s and then you can control it as you expect.

PS: I didn't test this before posting. Hope this will work and help you. If you have any problems regarding this answer or if you want to add something more and you have doubts about how to do it, please just comment on it here.

Comment: I've considered this approach but the problem is that since it's a `view`, it will mess with existing layouts. It also means that I'll have to add other layers of logic such as `accessibilityLabel` etc to the wrapper which I think will cause new issues.

Comment: Yeah... May be... But, according to my knowledge, this is the approach to do this. I don't think it will make new issues. Better to have a try if you prefer...